# locating all argument numbers in bash script

Tags: bash, grep

I have a script file written in Bash. what I'm trying to do is locate all the arguments used in the script ($1,$2,$3....) 
I've tried using:

```
grep -o '$[0-9]' $1
```

but that gives me seperate digits. for example, if I have $54 somewhere in the script,
I will only get $5. how can I get the whole number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use quantifier `+` to grab one or more digits:

```
grep -o '$[0-9]\+' "$1"
```

Comment: brilliant, thanx. can you maybe explain in a few words what it does exactly?

Comment: Yes sure. Your pattern `[0-9]` matches single digit only. Whereas `[0-9]\+` matches 1 or more digits. Here `+` is called quantifier in regex.

Comment: why do I need the `\$` in the begining?

Comment: I actually have removed `\$` and made it `$` since you are not using egrep or `grep -E` that supports extended regex. Usually `$` means end of line in regex and `$` needs to be escaped to match literal `$`

Comment: but if I use `' '`, doesn't that eliminate the need for \ ?

Comment: Yes I have already removed `\$` but if if you `grep -E` then you must use: `grep -Eo '\$[0-9]+'` due to reason I explained above.

Comment: Single quotes inhibit shell substitution but the regex itself, after shell processing, needs to contain a backslash. Compare to how a lone dot `.` matches any character, and a backslashed dot `\.` matches a literal dot and nothing else.